# Preciso de explicaçoes do modo OUT e INOUT PL/SQL e Mysql procedure

Tags: mysql, oracle, pl-sql, stored-procedures

Bom, eu coloquei PL/SQL e mysql porque esses dois modos tem nas procedures tanto do Oracle e mysql mas enfim..
O modo IN eu entendi que ele funciona como uma constant, ele é passado pelo parametro e não pode ser alterado dentro da procedure..
Mas eu estou na duvida no modo OUT e INOUT, eu vi que o out pode ser alterado dentro da procedure mas ele não "retorna" um valor. Qual a funcionalidade dele então? e o modo INOUT?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Conforme a [documentação do oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28370/subprograms.htm#LNPLS00805) os parâmetros out se comportam como uma variável não inicializada, logo independente do valor que passar no parâmetro, o método receberá um valor null como padrão, permitindo altera-lo, retornado o valor na variável utilizada. Os parâmetros In Out se comportam como uma variável inicializada, o método receberá o valor no parâmetro e é possível altera-lo também,  retornando o valor na variável utilizada no parâmetro. Segue abaixo um simples exemplo da utilização no oracle:

```
declare
  Letra CHAR;

  procedure AlteraOut(pLetra out char) is
  begin
    dbms_output.put_line('O valor do parâmetro out é: '||pLetra);
    pLetra := 'B';
  end;

  procedure AlteraInOut(pLetra in out char) is
  begin
    dbms_output.put_line('O valor do parâmetro in out é: '||pLetra);
    pLetra := 'C';
  end; 

begin
  Letra := 'A';

  AlteraOut(Letra);
  dbms_output.put_line('O Valor depois do procedimento out é: '||Letra);

  AlteraInOut(Letra);
  dbms_output.put_line('O Valor depois do procedimento in out é: '||Letra);  
end;
```

O conceito no mysql é o mesmo, conforme este [artigo](https://www.oficinadanet.com.br/artigo/2088/criando_stored_procedures_no_mysql)